# Can I alter an HSTORE column to JSON datatype?

Tags: postgresql, json, hstore

Is there a way to modify an existing column of `HSTORE` datatype (that has data) to `JSON` datatype in a Postgres database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple use [`hstore_to_json` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) to get a `json` out of a `hstore`. To change the table you can use the [`ALTER TABLE` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ALTER your_column_name TYPE json USING hstore_to_json(your_column_name);
```

There is `hstore_to_jsonb` too if you want `jsonb` instead of `json`.

Comment: Thought it's worth mentioning. This only works for Posgresql 9.3 version and above.

Comment: Do you know whether there any performance benefits of doing so?